# Cannot connect to SSIS ,dtsruntimewrap exception 0xC00160AC

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

## **How Can I Fix This Issue:(?**

Cannot connect to ..

===================================

Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

---

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()

===================================

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00160AC (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap)

---

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=506689

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.GetServerInfo(String server, String& serverVersion)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.SmoEnum.DTSEnum.GetData(EnumResult erParent)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData(Request req, Object ci)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.GetData(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object connectionInfo, Request request)

===================================

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00160AC (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap)

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.ApplicationClass.GetServerInfo(String bstrMachineName, String& serverVersion)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.GetServerInfo(String server, String& serverVersion)

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3yjS.jpg)

[Version Of My SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqrTu.jpg)

I also Fix The Grant Permission But Still On This Error..

Answer (score 0):

The version of SQL Server Management Studio should match the version of SSIS.

"SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) - SSMS version 17.x or later doesn't support connecting to the legacy SQL Server Integration Services service. "
quoted from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15#supported-sql-offerings